# Rails -v saying wrong rails version on Mac OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal, version

I've been trying to uninstall rails because it was on 4.1.0.rc1 and I wanted 4.0.0, so I ran

```
gem uninstall rails -v 4.1.0.rc1
```

And it said it was uninstalled successfully but typing

```
rails -v
```

still gives me 4.1.0.rc1

I tried running

```
gem cleanup
```

but it still is giving me the wrong version, I've quit the terminal and opened it back up and everything and am still getting the wrong version.

I just want to make sure that I am using the right version and everything is running smoothly. I've only been recently getting into ruby and learning how to install things in the terminal (I'm a recent mac convert) so all this stuff kind of wigs me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the gemfile in your project.

It should have this line

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
```

Go to your projects directory

and run

```
rails -v
```

This should return

```
Rails 4.0.0
```

If you do a rails -v outside any rails folder it show the newest version you have. But , inside a rails project folder it uses the version defined in the gem file.

When you greate a new rails project you can run

```
rails _<*version*>_ new <application_name>
```

in the case of 4.0.0

```
rails _4.0.0_ new myapp
```

---

This will return the rails versions you have

```
gem list | grep rails
```

if this returns

```
rails (4.0.3, 4.0.0, 3.2.12)
```

and you run

```
gem uninstall railties -v 4.0.3
```

you go to back to rails 4.0.0 on the global system. But again in each rails project you be at whatever version that's specified in the gemfile.

Comment: so is there a way I can have it always default to a certain version when running the new command? And do I need to have that version installed or does it install it at that directory?